# Accessing the Twitter Stream API with Twitter4J and OAuth

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, twitter4j

I want to access the Public streaming API sample using Twitter4J.
I have created an Application on Twitter and generated the relevant keys and tokens (using the Twitter portal).

But it keeps failing authentication.

Here is the code according to the documentation. A lot of the existing forum posts are out of date.

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXX");
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXXXX");
cb.setOAuthAccessToken("xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");   

OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(cb.build());
TwitterStreamFactory factory = new TwitterStreamFactory();
this.twitterStream = factory.getInstance(auth);
this.twitterStream.addListener(listener);
this.twitterStream.sample();
```

The error I get is:

```
401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or         incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the      system clock is in sync.
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/sample.json?stall_warnings=true'. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can not remember as it was so long ago! In the end, I had to manually make the connection and open the stream myself without a library.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to authenticate and receive the twitterstream:

```
private static  void listen() throws InterruptedException,TwitterException{

    ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configurationBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("*************")
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("******************")
        .setOAuthAccessToken("*******************")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("************");

    Configuration configuration= configurationBuilder.build();
    TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(configuration).getInstance();

    twitterStream.addListener(new twitter4j.StatusListener() {

        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            System.out.println("Status: {}"+ status);
        }

        public void onException(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error callback"+ ex);
        }

        public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {

        }

        public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int i) {

        }

        public void onScrubGeo(long l, long l1) {

        }

        public void onStallWarning(StallWarning stallWarning) {

        }

    });
    twitterStream.sample();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    twitterStream.shutdown();
}
```

Hope this helps. The key for me was creating the TwitterStreamFactory passing a configuration object to its constructor. That's how it can authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for 401 error is Authentication Failure. It can happen due to two reasons

- **Incorrect Credentials** in Configuration [Different ways for Configuring credentials are explained [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html)]
- **Incorrect System Clock** [Sync the System clock even thought you feel that the time is correct]

The second reason can be the cause when you are able to Post a tweet, View timeline etc using API and not able to use twitter streaming.[**You get 401 when using streaming API only**]

Comment: system clock?  on the OS?  Why would that matter?